# Is A1 found between values B and C, where B is the start number and C is the end number, regardless of row? Excel

Tags: excel

Is A1 found between values B and C, where B is the start number and C is the end number, regardless of row? In excel.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N547W.png)

[image]

I am trying to figure if the transcription start site coordinate in A, is found within a gene (start coordinate is in B and end coordinate is in C). If so, write "yes", if not, write "no".

Comment: "regardless of row"? So you should not check A1 against B1 and C1, A2 against B2 and C2 etc.?

Comment: Write yes/no where ?

Comment: Looks like they would all fail; none of the A column values are in between the corresponding B and C column values. Original poster needs to be more specific.

Comment: @Marc A7 will be yes

Comment: I want to look in all rows for columns B and C. So no, not "Does A1 fall between B1 and C1." But more, "Does A1 fall between B1 and C1? Or B2 and C2? Or B3 and C3? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to do something like this formula, entered into `D1`?

```
=IF(AND(A1<=C1,A1>=B1),"YES","NO")
```

Comment: I think he wants {=IF(AND(A1<=C:C,A1>=B:B),"YES","NO")}

Comment: I want to look in all rows for columns B and C. So no, not "Does A1 fall between B1 and C1." But more, "Does A1 fall between B1 and C1? Or B2 and C2? Or B3 and C3? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in the first row of an unused column to the right.

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$25)/(($B$1:$B$25<=A1)*($C$1:$C$25>=A1)), 1), TEXT(,))
```

Fill down as necessary. Any matching pair will return the row number it is on.

[image: found_between_others]

And **no**... I did not feel like retyping your sample data.